# itextsharp and livecycle

Tags: c#, .net, itext, acrobat

I've managed to create a template (for an invoice) in livecycle. I've chosen dynamic PDF instead of static PDF because of a few fields that needed to autoresize (like address, product name).

Now I use itextsharp to complete the fields, and it works if I save the PDF as acrobat 7 dynamic xml form.

The problem is that the fields are editable. in order to resolve this in itextsharp I have to put formflattening = true, but then when I open my PDF I can't see any more the whole address for example, or the full text that made the field to expand.

Has anyone an idea how to make the PDF non-editable after I've set the fields?
if I use adobe reader pro to build the fields, they don't expand in order to accommodate the full length of the text.

Answer (score 2):

In adobe livecycle make your form fields Calculated ReadOnly. This will prevent anyone from editing the form fields.